How common it is in the US to ask for technical help from the supervisor as a PostDoc in CS?
I want to know if it common to ask the supervisor about a technical question (in coding or in  the theory behind the code) as a PostDoc in computer science (in US or even EU)?
Is it seen as "normal" or would project a technical weakness and thus communicate a lack of confidence in the technical aspect of the work by the postdoc which would in turn lessen the reposed confidence from the supervisor to the postdoc.

It seems like this would depend entirely on the question asked.

I would much rather have a postdoc who admits they are stuck or confused, than one who pretends to understand things and then makes mistakes...

What would be the point of having a supervisor if you couldn't ask them questions?

I was asking about a specific type of questions. your comment is not helpful at all

Discussions on technical issues are very common. That is true about the supervisor or others in the field. The coffee room in large departments can be one of the most productive places of all. Big questions don't have easy answers. Different people have different backgrounds and different perspectives as well as different insights.
It would be a mistake (IMO) not to ask if some question is holding you up. Among other things, even things we know won't always be at the forefront of our thinking.
Such questions can also lead to new insights and new directions. Working alone in a cave is one of the least productive methodologies of all.
If your PI is overly grumpy, however, tread lightly with them, but not necessarily with others. If research were easy, no one would pay you to do it.
